# How to replace layout of a fragment under a tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am pretty new in android programming. What I have is an app with some tabs, each associate with some fragments. I want to change the layout of the fragment. But I don't want to mess up with the tabs. I am trying to achieve this from a class that extends AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method. I tried to inflate the layout, but it also affects the tabs. I just want to change the fragment only. Here is the code so far:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    lInflater = inflater;
    mContainer = container;
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.symptoms_layout, container, false);

    textList = new ArrayList();
    final LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll);
    Button mButton = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

    Button test = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_search_sym);

    cAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(textList,getActivity().getApplicationContext(),test);

    ListView lView = (ListView)mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_symptoms);
    lView.setAdapter(cAdapter);

    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                Log.d("SymFrag",String.valueOf(cAdapter.getCount()));
                String[] list = new String[cAdapter.getCount()];
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < cAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    Log.d("SymFrag", "Im in for loop");

                    String temp = cAdapter.getItem(i).toString();
                    sb.append(temp);
                    sb.append(",");

                }

                /*new BackgroundManager(new BackgroundManager.AsyncResponse() {
                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(String output) {
                        String[] out = output.split(",");
                        for(int i = 0; i < out.length; i++){
                            Log.d("ProFin",out[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }).execute(sb.toString());*/

                new BackgroundManager(getActivity(),lInflater,mContainer).execute(sb.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SymFag",e.toString());
            }

        }

    });

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            mLinearLayout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_added,null));

            TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.symtex);
            TextView t = (TextView)mLinearLayout.findViewWithTag("tex");
            textList.add(tv.getText().toString());


            t.setText(tv.getText());*/
            Button bSearch = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_search_sym);
            TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.symtex);
            textList.add(tv.getText().toString());
            bSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Above is the fragment I want to update/change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_added, mLinearLayout)`?